# Mailchimp Newsletter archive generation via js and ssl doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ssl, archive, mailchimp

i'm stucking at an issue with Mailchimp and the way of integrating newsletter archive widget which gets generated via JS script

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://us3.campaign-archive1.com/generate-js/?u=ac6976e87d9e9f0eac4bbf19c&fid=9185&show=10" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When adding `https` or just using `//` this doesn't work and without https .. archive isn't displayed ..

https://bitshares.org/newsletter/2015/archive/2014/

Maybe somebody can help me out here…

Thanks in advance for help
c

Comment: Have you added any campaigns to the folder you got the embed code from? See http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/archives/set-up-your-campaign-archive

Answer (score 0):

I found something of an answer here http://cantonbecker.com/etcetera/2015/how-to-use-mailchimps-archive-js-code-if-your-site-is-ssl-encrypted/

$mailchimpArchives = file_get_contents('http://us9.campaign-archive2.com/generate-js/?u= abc123&fid=12345&show=10');
echo('' . $mailchimpArchives . '');

Basically, you are reading the javascript archive html content into a PHP variable and then serving that content up from your website.